# Help with debunking pseudoscience physics claim

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, gamma-rays

I read this paper (PHYSIQUE MICRO-VIBRATOIRE ET FORCES INVISIBLES par A. de BELIZAL et P. A. MOREL) that claims that purely magnetic gamma rays exist. They call them negative green. They show pictures, like the one attached here,

[image]

claiming to have captured images of gamma rays on photographic film (not clear if the picture is a print or a negative) but they also say that they couldn't detect any gamma rays using a geiger counter. So they hypothesize that they discovered a new type of energy that is mostly magnetic. This seems to completely defy the laws of physics.

Can anyone help me to debunk this claim?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Pretty clear what my questions are. Can purely magnetic form of gamma radiation exist? 

Does picture look like gamma radiation effect on film or some artifact? 

Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with down voting and closing questions like this. The OP isn't supporting junk science. He has come across some and is asking people who should know if there is anything to it. We should be more open to this.

Comment: The title of the book linked in rob's answer, «ESSAI DE RADIESTHÉSIE VIBRATOIRE» means "A test of vibrational magic-aura-divination." Your friend may be a *long* way down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Looks like scratched film/fabric to me unless there's something else going on but that's a guess given the very limited info about the provenance - more like just reporting the "sniff test" to me. But if I wanna get charitable, then presumably the trails are supposed to be like a cloud chamber, right? In that case, not sure what is even being _claimed_ to be weird about them, so can't even try to explain anything. That said, that also shows it proves nothing.

Comment: "I disagree with down voting and closing questions like this. The OP isn't supporting junk science. He has come across some and is asking people who should know if there is anything to it. We should be more open to this."

Thank you. I appreciate it. I am sincere. I have background in Biology PH.D. but I am not an expert on physics. I know this is fringe idea. I would like to be able to intelligently defend why I think this idea is junk science. My primary argument is that you can't have magnetic wave without an electric one since they create each other.

Comment: "Looks like scratched film/fabric to me unless there's something else going on but that's a guess given the very limited info about the provenance" They claim it is emulsion film that shows evidence of being exposed to gamma rays.

Comment: I tabbed through to the relevant section in the document, and the authors don't appear to have any idea how photography works, either. Perhaps they'd seen a picture of a bubble chamber and knew that film could detect radiation (film exposed to radiation darkens) and thought the bubble chamber pictures were what happens to film. They spend pages talking about what appear to be small scratches and exposure jiggles on extremely magnified film as if they're pair-production trails in a bubble chamber.

Comment: gs that is what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Magnetic radiation (by which I assume you mean oscillations in the magnetic field) by itself cannot propagate without producing tandem oscillations in the electric field, by Ampere's and Faraday's laws. Moreover, a "purely" magnetic field vector can be transformed partially into an electric field vector by  the observer boosting to a different reference frame, per special relativity.

So you cannot have a wave purely in the magnetic field. It would be somewhat akin to trying to have an acoustic wave with only crests and no troughs.

Comment: That is all my understanding. They try to claim it is like nuclear magnetic resonance.

Comment: True, but remember using theory to defeat experiment can only go so far. Theory can definitely suggest a result is _likely_ wrong, as in this case for sure and this is what I'd say too, but experiment is still ultimately king in that if there's nothing _actually_ wrong with it, then the theory needs revision, and the experiment can only be truly "disproven" by analyzing it and actually naming the error. Just like if someone claims a perpetual work machine, 1st/2nd of thermo says "almost surely an error" but to be truly helpful we'd ideally like to _find_ the error, esp. on a site like this.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it. That is why I am questioning the idea of magnetic gamma radiation which is what they claim. They admit geiger counter detects nothing, but then make bold claim that it is because the gamma rays were in magnetic form. They make analogy to nuclear magnetic resonance. Anyone can make great theories. Since I can't make experiment to test it looking for obvious flaws to bring into question. Thanks.

Comment: I agree experiment trumps theory, all things being equal, but it seems like what this paper has is experimental readings, and they are using outlandish and incorrect theory to explain it.  There is most likely an explanation of the observations using known theory.

Answer (score 3):

I found a copy of the paper [here](https://doczz.fr/doc/478027/physique-micro-vibratoire-et-forces-invisibles). It is from 1976.  My French is weak, but on page 16 or so they divide electromagnetic waves into

> Il y a sept vibrations-couleurs visibles avec chacune ses infra et ses ultra, a savoir :
>
> Violet; Indigo; Bleu; Vert positif ou vert du spectre visible; Jaune; Orangé; Rouge,
>
> Puis cinq vibrations-couleurs invisibles avec également chacune leurs infra et leurs ultra, soit ;
>
> Infra-Rouge ; Noir; Vert négatif; Blanc; Ultra-violet.

You can probably stop reading there: “noir (black)” and “blanc (white)” are not parts of the electromagnetic spectrum, so “negative green” almost certainly isn’t either.

A few pages later they arrange these twelve “colors” in a ring, so that negative-green is opposite positive-green on the invisible side.  There’s just nothing there.  “Not even wrong,” in the jargon of debunkers.

I have no idea what’s happening in that photo, but I expect the effort-to-payoff ratio for figuring it it out would not be very good.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I need to kill they argument completely, so want to take out their main argument about negative green being magnetic form of gamma ray.

Comment: Re “I need”: is this a school assignment? do you have an employer who is wasting time trying to build some negative-green machine based on a photograph of a ghost from 45 years ago? have you been hired to ”prove” the theory by some proud family member? Or do you have a purely personal interest in this?

Comment: A Person told me. I want to show them clearly why it can't be true. 

I am Interested in debunking because it goes against everything I learned about physics, but I am not a expert on physics so I wanted to get my argument straight. Thanks for time.

 Thanks.

Comment: This is exact part they claim magenetic. "C'est qu'en effet nous nous trouvons ici en présence d'une énergie magnétique pure,
dont l'ordre de grandeur se situe au millionième ou au milliardième d'électrons-volts, alors
que la radio-activité connue libère des énergies qui se mesurent en millions d'électronsvolts.
Pour les mésons et les hypérons, c'est en milliards et dizaines de milliards qu'il faut
compter.

Comment: As one of my mentors liked to say, “nothing resembles a new effect quite so much as a mistake.” There are a lot of reasons that something might show up in a camera and not in a Geiger counter — for instance, the camera, the Geiger counter, or both could be broken. Twentieth-century physics is littered with “discoveries” which turned out to be mirages. A history of such mirages, like N-rays or the 17 keV neutrino or the 2005-era pentaquarks, would make more fruitful study than a deep dive into this particular paper.